# edit word content control from with in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, csom, jsom, word

I want to add data to a word document programmatically that uploaded to SharePoint 2013, For this purpose I know that I can use content controls but I do not know how !

Can i edit value of word content control from with in SharePoint 2013 with JSOM or CSOM or something else ?